# ASP.Net Forms Authentication - Request does not redirect to loginUrl in IE

Tags: asp.net, iis, webforms, web-config, forms-authentication

I have the login page in the next path:

`~/Views/Users/Login.aspx`

I set that path as `loginUrl` in the forms label inside the `Web.Config` file:

```
<forms loginUrl="~/Views/Users/Login.aspx" />
```

When I try to display my web site in Google Chrome using the root web side URL, the browser redirect to the login page without problems, but It does not work in IE. It work fine if I move the `Login.aspx` file to the project root and change the `loginUrl`:

```
<forms loginUrl="Login.aspx" />
```

Do you known what is the problem with the path `~/Views/Home/Index.aspx` as `loginUrl` ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: According to your description, I have created a test demo on my side, it works well. I have used the iE11 to test with your login url. [Image as this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ewZPD.png). Could you please tell me which error you have seen in the IE browser? Do you remove all the cache for the IE browser?

Comment: After remove all the cache for the IE browser It worked fine. Thanks!